# Producer&Consumer и пулы потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть два пула потоков:

- Отправляют http запросы.
- Обрабатывают то, что пришло (например, маппят из json в объекты).

Главные герои:

1. **RequestManager** - имеет метод push(Request), который отдает
   свободному в данный момент потоку Request для его отправки на
   сервер.
2. **RequestSender** (Runnable) - реализует отправку
   запроса, который пришел от RequestManager. Ответ от сервера
   (HttpResponse) должен быть передан ResponseManager.
3. **ResponseManager** - имеет пул потоков-обработчиков и метод push(HttResponse), который получает на вход ответ от сервера и
   передает его на обработку свободному в данный момент
   потоку-обработчику.
4. **ResponseHandler** (Runnable), принимает
   очередной ответ от сервера и передает его сначала preProcessor'у,
   который должен иметь базовую логику обработки ошибок: сервер
   оказался недоступным, отправили запрос не в том формате, и тд, если
   же все ок, вызывается метод handle(), который каждый может
   переопределить в зависимости от задачи.

**Дело вот в чем:** во время исполнения может много чего пойти "не так". Например, возможны ситуации, когда сервер вернул только часть результата (500 сотрудников из 10 000) и просит проитерироваться, добавляя к запросу offset. В таком случае ResponseHandler должен как то добыть запрос, который был сделан и отправить его к RequestManager'у с offset'ом. Но черт возьми тогда данный запрос будет уже обрабатывать какой то другой поток-обработчик из пула, а хочется обрабатывать его в одном обработчике, склеяв вместе все ответы. Еще одна ситуация - токен, который олицетворяет сессию прикажет долго жить, а значит один из потоков пула RequestManager, который является носителем этого токена и подшивает его ко всем запросам, должен будет убит. Поэтому опять же RequestHandler должен будет как то достучаться до RequestManager'a и повлиять на его работу. Имеет кучу циклических зависимостей. Отсюда вопросы - как бы вы реализовали все это? Существуют ли хорошие паттерны, которые уместны в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы зря пытаетесь привязать запрос к потоку.

Запрос (а точнее все стадии его обработки) должен представляться объектом (совокупностью объектов), который "путешествует" по очередям ваших менеджеров  и должен быть совершенно независим от данных конкретного потока-обработчика.

Например, в этом случае незавершенный запрос легко может быть возвращен (с новым заданием в своем теле) в RequestManager (и далее в RequestSender и далее опять ... в нужный обработчик).

Собственно, такой подход близок к event driving (т.е. управление по событиям (а если вдуматься, то это он и есть)).